# How does CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list) work?

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons

```
List<String> list = null;  // line1
List<String> list = Collections.emptyList(); // line2

if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {  // line3
   System.out.println("empty");  // line4
} else {
   list.forEach(value -> System.out.println(value));  // line5
}
```

If I initialize the list as per line2, why the if check prints the output as empty? But I change the check to `list == null`, it works fine. i.e. the code iterates on the empty list.

Comment: "If I initialize the list as per line2, why the if check prints empty?" Because you're initializing it to an empty list. It's right there in the name of the method.

Comment: `CollectionUtils.isEmpty()` returns true if there are no elements in the list. If the list is `null` it can't hold any elements and thus it is as empty as an existing list without any elements (like the one created in line 2). Normally you use that method if you don't need to distinguish between null and empty lists, i.e. you just do something if there are elements in the list which also requires it to be non-null.

Comment: Very clear in [javadocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEmpty-java.util.Collection-): *Null-safe check if the specified collection is empty. Null returns true.*

Comment: Wait... did you expect that `isEmpty()` will be false for an `emptyList`?

Comment: @Amongalen - Out of curiosity... yes!

Comment: "... it works fine. i.e. the code iterates on the empty list." - yes the code would run and "iterate" over the empty list (i.e. do nothing). However you'd then get no output and might wonder why nothing is happening (depends on your expectations and requirements) and since you need a check anyway you could as well check for `null` and `isEmpty()` in one call.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why would you expect `isEmpty()` to return false for an empty list? That would be very confusing.

Comment: @Thomas - the requirement is such if the list is empty the loop should work. This, I have made the change now to only check if the <code>list==null</code>, then print empty in the console.

Comment: Reading the javadocs makes it clear now that CollectionUtils.isEmpty() will return true even if the list is empty! and it was not meeting the requirements.

Comment: @DanielAtlas I have to say those are really weird requirements to expect `isEmpty()` to lie when it comes to an empty list. Every empty list is empty, by definition.

Comment: I second Amongalen: an empty list is empty, that's a fact. If you expect the loop to run on any non-null list then you need to check for `null` only - and in that case I'd change the message to "list is null" (meaning the list doesn't exist).

Comment: I agree with both of u but a requirement is a requirement!

Comment: The actual surprising behavior is that a method named `isEmpty` actually performs a `null`-check. But that’s the reason why I don’t use these 3rd party library methods whose sole purpose is to perform questionable `null`-checks. If your requirement is to perform a `null`-check, just perform a `null`-check, i.e. `if(list == null) System.out.println("empty"); else list.forEach(value -> System.out.println(value));`. Your requirement surely doesn’t include to use an inappropriate 3rd party library method.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger.

Answer (score 0):

JavaDoc:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Collection<?> coll)

Null-safe check if the specified collection is empty.

Null returns true.
```

Implemented:

```
return coll == null || coll.isEmpty();
```

Comment: Writing real code would be easier: `return coll == null || coll.isEmpty();`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't agree with the above statement. Always we need to write less code and the code should be readable.